# React - use button for redirect link

Tags: reactjs, redirect, href

I'm new to `React` so sorry if this is too basic.

I am trying to add a button in my app to redirect it to Spotify.

This is how I'm trying to do it, so far.

```
class Spotify extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick () {
    console.log('Success!')
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='button__container'>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Link your Spotify account
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Spotify;
```

Now, what is the best way of linking the above button to:

```
 <a href="http://localhost:8888"></a>
```

Comment: any particular reason why you can't just add your <a href="http://localhost:8888"></a> where your <button> is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
class Spotify extends Component {    
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='button__container'>
        <a className='button' role="button" href="http://someurl.com">
          Link your Spotify account
        </a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Spotify;
```

If your component doesn't require state, consider refactoring the above code into a stateless component like so:

```
export const Spotify = () => (
      <div className='button__container'>
        <a className='button' role="button" href="http://someurl.com">
          Link your Spotify account
        </a>
      </div>
);
```

If you are just trying to display a link, an anchor tag will work just fine. You can add `target="_blank"` to your anchor tag to have it open in a new tab.

Comment: right on! I added a comment to the author's question because I wanted to understand what made them think they couldn't just go ahead and use the anchor instead of button.

Comment: actually I need state, because I will need this button to appear only if user is not already authenticated. could you please update you answer considering state?

Comment: I mean keeping the `onClick` function